# Air Asia and Air Asia X on same flight, what's the difference?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, price, airasia

There's a flight from KUL to MEL at night that gets into MEL the following morning.  It comes up (same time, same plane, same everything) in my searches twice, however - as Air Asia, and Air Asia X.  However, the Air Asia one is $2 more than the Air Asia X.

[The flight in question, when it flew a few hours ago](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/XAX214)

Is this just variation in pricing, or is there an actual difference in the tickets? It's on an A330, which implies it's Air Asia X, as according to [their site](http://www.airasia.com/ask/template.do?id=504):

> ### What is the difference between AirAsia and AirAsiaX?
>
> **AirAsia**
>
> Operates flights that are inside 4 hours flight time. AirAsia utilises
>   aircraft with single class cabin and seating configuration. AirAsia
>   operates Airbus A320 which has a seating capacity of 180 passengers.
>
> **AirAsiaX**
>
> Operates flights that has more than 4 hours flying time, which is also
>   termed as long haul flights. AirAsiaX utilises aircraft with single
>   class cabin but with premium and economy class seating. AirAsiaX
>   operates Airbus A330 which has a seating capacity of 377 passengers.

So I'm wondering if it's just a case of Air Asia trying to sell the same tickets, or if there's a difference in the service one would receive (meals etc)?

Comment: Could it be that this is a multi-hop flight that takes more than four hours in total, but less than four on each hop, so it would technically qualify for either category?

Comment: @SimonRichter I'm guessing the leg going to MEL isn't less than 4 hours. At any rate, from a quick flightaware search, this appears to be a direct flight from KUL. Also, OP said that it's the same flight and equipment on both is listed as A330, so it's definitely operated  by Air Asia X (probably either [this flight](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/XAX212/history/20150807/0540Z/WMKK/YMML) or [this flight](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/XAX214/history/20150806/1430Z/WMKK/YMML).)

Comment: @SimonRichter direct flight, leaves 11ish pm. And yes, it's the second flight in reirab's comment.  I'll add in to question.

Comment: Airasia and Airasia X are 2 different companies, and they are both listed in  Malaysia exchange market.  Airasia used to be the parent company of latter, but it owns 16% shares now.

Comment: Definitely direct flight, I flew that leg a week ago today with AirAsia X.  Decent flight actually, the nasi goreng is pretty tasty too.

Comment: You have to buy food and even water separately. Air Asia X is used for their international kegs mostly. CMB KUL is an AirAsiaX, but it only takes 3 hours. So both are the same except for branding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same tickets.  No difference in service.  There is a difference in service between the budget and the flat bed class, but no difference otherwise.

As you point out, the A330 suggests AirAsia X and the fact that it's a flight over 4 hours also suggests that; so it's an AirAsia X flight, whatever they're saying it as.

Judging by the general quality of their website, I'd say it's a bug rather than anything clever like trying to sell more tickets.